# C# (wpf) after creating object instance i can not reuse it

Tags: c#, wpf, object, instance

I am working on small project, and I am trying to use object to store data. Its only: name, year and price to be stored (max 10 items).

```
//On click I get user input and I create new object instance
//This is addmovie.xaml.cs 

     private void btn_add_movie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                string m = input_movie_name.Text;
                Movie NewMovie = new Movie { Name = m };
            }

// This is Movie class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeNiro
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string genre { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Moviez { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:
This is movielist.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DeNiro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for movielist.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class movielist : Page
    {
        public movielist()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            String test = NewMovie.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I use NewMovie.Name?

Is there a way to create new Movie instance in movielist.xaml.cs and to get previously stored data from it? Please help.

Comment: Because it only exists in that function.  You need to store it in a class and pass the class.

Comment: You need to store the data somewhere. E.g create a property of type `List<Movie> Movies;` in your class and call `Movies.Add(newMovie);`

Comment: @KlausGütter I have already tried that, but it wont let me pick Moviez before creating new instance... http://prntscr.com/mih414

Comment: @SLaks I am having problem storing it in a class, here is ss: prntscr.com/migso7 It wont let me choose Movie.Name... Movie.Name = "test";

Answer (score 0):

I will try to do it as clear as I can:

The problem is because when you define a variable inside a function without *return* or without passing it "return" value to another function or to class property or reference, the data is just wasted (this is not the fully programmatically explanation but it will help you understand)

Now in your code, after the button is clicked, a new instance of the class `Movie` (as you defined it: *name, year and price*) is created. and that's it, the function finishes, doing nothing with `NewMovie`.

What you want to do is to pass this instance to a new function:

```
public partial class movielist: Page
{

    // This is list, unlike array you can insert things to it as much as you want
    private List<Movie> MoviesList = new List<Movie>();

    public movielist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddMovie(string newMovie)
    {
        this.MoviesList.Add(newMovie); // Adds new movie to the movies list
        String test = NewMovie.Name;
    }

}
```

And in:

```
private void btn_add_movie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string m = input_movie_name.Text;
    Movie NewMovie = new Movie { Name = m };
    this.movielistInstance.AddMovie(NewMovie);
}
```

And don't forget to set `private movielist movielistInstance = new movielist();` in `addmovie.xaml.cs` class

and for next time, please post the whole `addmovie.xaml.cs`, it will make us a lot easier to answer.